# How to use IF in Insert trigger?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 table person and user, each registration or insert user by type "app" default value. it will auto execute statement that inser into person. then take the last id and update into user.person_id FK. i got error "Unknown table 'user' in field list". i test many combination. like `pandora`.`user`.`user_type`. it give other error. how to exactly access table in insert or in this case?

Table definition

```
person table
=======
person_id PK
firstname DEFAULT NULL
lastname DEFAULT NULL

user polymorphism table 
=======
user_id PK
username
password
user_type DEFAULT app
person_id FK
```

Trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER UserAFTER_INSERT AFTER INSERT ON `user` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (`user.user_type` = "app") THEN
    INSERT INTO `person` VALUES ();      
    SET @personId := SELECT `person_id` FROM `person` ORDER BY `person_id` DESC LIMIT 1; 
    UPDATE `user` SET `person_id` = @personId;
  END IF;
END
```

Comment: You refer to the row that was just inserted as NEW.  `IF (NEW.user_type = "app")`.  With that said, you can't update the same row in a trigger.  The way to structure this type of thing is not to have a person_id in the user table.  Instead, you make the new inserted person_id the same as the user_id.

Comment: @gview i design object that can re-use, in my design, i think person can have many user. user can be anything, can be user site, user proxy-server. app in default means. its own app. it seperate that thing. so if the type is app. it means later user can fill that real identify. so person identify is not must in application.

Comment: @gview ok, now it got error `Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'user' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.`. it seeems trigger insert dont allow update in sametimes. it give error in update statement.

Comment: I told you this in the answer I provided you.  You can not update User in the user trigger.  You CAN insert into Person, as the trigger I provided does.

Comment: @gview your answer is one person have 1 user. in my case, person can have many user in different type even multi user in same type. ex. person can have 2 user in facebook website. person can have 3 user identify proxy-server. same person can have 3 user in instagram. so the table should be what the object is. the object should be re-use. i think if no solution in mysql ways. i implement that in logical code.

Comment: @gview in basic design, object can be more clarify in table lets say user_sites, user_proxyservers. but it totally bring nightmare in bloat table.

Comment: What you describe sounds like "person_system" rows, that resolve a many-to-many relationship between a person and a system.  system table would have rows for (facebook, proxy-server, instagram, etc).  From your description a person can have many person_system rows.  That would be additional table structure.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues in your trigger.  The first answer is that you refer to the newly created user row (since this is a trigger on the user table) as NEW.

```
IF (NEW.user_type = "app") THEN
```

However you will soon encounter the fact that you can't update the newly created row in the trigger.

You don't need to do that, and to implement your subtype structure in the database, you should not have a person_id row in user.

What you want to do, is make the primary key of the person row the same as the primary key of the user row.  This is what connects them.  Technically this is refered to as a One-To-One relationship.

Remove person_id from User, and implement a trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UserAFTER_INSERT AFTER INSERT ON `user` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.user_type = "app" THEN
    INSERT INTO person (person_id, firstname, lastname) VALUES (NEW.user_id, '', '');           
  END IF;
END
```

As you create new subtype tables, you will likely update this trigger with similar inserts for the other subtypes (user.user_type) you have.

Comment: u are wrong in here, user is belong to person. person is the first object. not person belong to user. person can have many user in several different type. like site, proxy-server. u have to think, single object that can be re-use. i dont want to create again - again in other project that specific for that application. u just follow my statement. i need that ways.

Comment: i try to set with `NEW.user_type` it bring error `Table 'user.person_id' doesn't exist`.

Comment: That is not how you implement a subtype.  No user does not belong to person, and if you consider what you are trying to do, you should realize that there is no way something that doesn't even exist (a person row) can "own" something that does -- a user.  A user has many different subtypes based on the user_type (person, app etc.)  as you designed it.  When you create a User that is a user_type of "person" then you create a person row.  Because the id's will be the same, you can then match user/person because the id value will be the same for both.  User comes first, then person.